# Handling with Edit Suggestions

Tags: discussion, editing, review

Well in my review chains i often find edit suggestions, so far so good.
Sometimes the editors change a lot of information into some Answers ( or Questions), so that i would say it's a substantial change in the Answer, which might not be intended or missed by the original poster of that answer/question.

This makes me wish to have an option to communicate with the editor before rejecting the edit like: please write an own answer as this is a substantial change to the original answer. Or it would be better to communicate these substantial changes by commenting the original answer.

Would this be possible?

Maybe such substantial edits should pass through a "longer" review chain.
Personally i prefer simple editing: correcting typos and mistakes, formatting, but i won't never delete a chapter from an answer and replace it or add a hole new chapter, as this couldn't go ahead with the intention of the original poster, if not communicated!

I wonder how do others see this?

Comment: Related MSE discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147669/132874

Comment: @goldPseudo ok, but this only answers the part about communication between editor and reviewer